# Grammaticality - 'why should we make us merry'? (1892 UK)

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns, history, reflexive-pronouns

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=2IE-AAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA33&ots=pUQWrtwBkx&dq=%22%20why%20should%20we%20make%20us%20merry%20Because%20a%20year%20of%20it%20is%20gone%22&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q=%22%20why%20should%20we%20make%20us%20merry%20Because%20a%20year%20of%20it%20is%20gone%22&f=false) Act 1, Scene 3, The Foresters, by Alfred Tennyson

“...if this life of ours
Be a good glad thing, why should we make **us** merry
Because a year of it is gone? but Hope
Smiles from the threshold of the year to come,
Whispering 'it will be happier'...”

1. Does the above mean: why should we make **ourselves** merry on a birthday because one year has lapsed? If so, why was the objective pronoun **us** used, and not the [reflexive <s>emphatic</s>](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/reflexive-emphatic-pronouns/) **ourselves**?

2. Why write ' we make **us** merry '?  Why not just:   3. 'we become merry '?

Comment: Another link on reflexive v emphatic pronouns: http://www.englishgrammar.org/reflexive-emphatic-pronouns-exercise-2/

Comment: Obiter dictum: I didn't apply blockquotes to the poem because when I tried doing so, the formatting was ruined.

Comment: Also, I lighted upon this poem while reading http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/12/31/new-year-quotes_n_6397600.html

Answer (score 4):

Act I, Scene III, *The Foresters*
Alfred Tennyson (1892)

> > “...if this life of ours
> >     Be a good glad thing, why should we make **us** merry
> >     Because a year of it is gone? but Hope
> >     Smiles from the threshold of the year to come,
> >     Whispering 'it will be happier'...”
>
> 1. Does the above mean: why should we make **ourselves** merry on a birthday because one year has lapsed?

Yes.

> If so, why was the objective pronoun **us** used, and not the [reflexive <s>emphatic</s>](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/reflexive-emphatic-pronouns/) **ourselves**?

**Us** *is* the reflexive pronoun.

But not the modern one. Examples of this phrase *to make merry* are listed in the OED beginning in the 1300s, with earliest uses employing a reflexive pronoun. This date puts us plump [in the middle](http://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/timeline.html) of [Middle English](http://www.thehistoryofenglish.com/history_middle.html) (ca 1150-1500).

Beginnng in earlier "[Old English](http://wmich.edu/medieval/resources/IOE/index.html)" and continuing in Middle English (see [this doc file](http://hildegard.tristram.de/sem/files/lange.doc)), **the reflexive pronoun was the same as the personal pronoun, with *-self* thrown in on occasion for emphasis.**

By [early modern English](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-time/grammar-in-early-modern-english/), ca 1600,

> The earlier use of the simple objective pronouns me, thee, us, and so on [as reflexive pronouns], became restricted largely to poetic use during the period, as in this example from Milton’s *Paradise Lost:* ‘Take to *thee* from among the Cherubim *Thy* choice of flaming Warriours’. **Forms in *-self* (which early had been restricted to emphatic use) now became the usual ones;** plurals—with *-selves* (replacing *-self*) after plural pronouns—made their appearance in the early sixteenth century [emphasis mine].

---

**2**

> Why write 'we make **us** merry'?

Old lines die hard.

Simple internet searches show that the phrase *make us merry* continued to be used in both prosaic language and poetic, including **plays** such as the one you have quoted. These uses include those that retain *us* as a reflexive pronoun and those that use *us* as an object pronoun ('come here and make us merry'). The OED attests to the continual usage of the phrase from 1300 to the present.

Therefore:
A. the 700-year (to this date) popularity of "make us merry"
B. Because the author Tennyson wanted to use "make us merry"
C. Because Tennyson wanted to use "make us merry" in order to maintain the meter of his verse  (this is poetry, after all, and each line contains a certain amount of syllables)

**3**

> Why not just: 'we become merry'?

D. Because it is as bland as saltless butter (it is not poetic).
E. Because the [Merry Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merry_Men) would have risen up in rebellion had Tennyson done so.

> Friends,
>   I am only merry for an hour or two
>   Upon a birthday: if this life of ours
>   Be a good glad thing, *why should we make **us** merry*
>   Because a year of it is gone? but Hope
>   Smiles from the threshold of the year to come
>   Whispering ‘It will be happier;’ and old faces
>   Press round us, and warm hands close with warm hands,
>   And thro’ the blood the wine leaps to the brain
>   Like April sap to the topmost tree, that shoots
>   New buds to heaven, whereon the throstle rock’d
>   Sings a new song to the new year—and you,
>   Strike up a song, my friends, and then to bed.

[Another source of the text](http://www.telelib.com/authors/T/TennysonAlfred/play/foresters/foresters0103.html)

Comment: "bland as saltless butter" – Good call! Though it's also worth noting that "we become merry" would say nothing about *who caused* the merriment. "We make us merry" says "we party", rather than "we watch a comedy and laugh".

Comment: Interesting side note. In Spanish, this is still accomplished with a reflexive form of the verb, which integrates an object pronoun. Thus the verb "divertirse" means to have fun, but literally it is "to divert oneself".  It is conjugated like this "me divertí" (I had fun) "nos divertimos" (we had fun) etc.  there are many reflexive verbs jn Spanish, even for actions we don't think of as such: "lavense las manos" (wash your hands)

Comment: Sí, the old: *I'm washing myself the hands.*

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your support. Would you mind enlarging on E? This sounds like a literary joke? I don't understand the allusion to Merry Men and rebellion?

Comment: Yes, tis a joke. The Merry Men who accompany Robin Hood--they would be upset and rise up in revolt against an author who chose such a poor expression as 'we became merry'. It is poor because it is not poetic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is what it means. "Ourselves" is indeed the correct pronoun, but in poetry, the rules of grammar are often bent. Normally, "ourselves" should be used.